# get selected multiple rows of checkbox by inserting no of rows in input box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables

[image]

How can i get selected checkbox of the datatable by inputing numbers

I'm trying to code a `bootstrap data table` which able to **select check box of the rows by** `inserting no of rows in the input box`

**I dont have any idea about how to do it.**

**e.g:** I typed number **three in the input box** then **automatically checkbox table of two rows will get selected** at [the beginning -> no problem]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="container text-center">
<label for="fname">insert number for select multiple check box</label>
<input type="number" id="selectcheckbox" name="selectcheckbox">
<table data-toggle="table" 
       data-classes="table table-hover table-condensed"
       data-row-style="rowColors"
       data-striped="true"
       data-sort-name="Quality"
       data-sort-order="desc"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-click-to-select="true"
       >
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
        <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="Product_Name" data-sortable="true">Product Name</th>
        <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="Quality" data-sortable="true">Quality</th>
        <th class="col-xs-6" data-field="Quantity" >Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
        <td></td>
        <td>Wheat</td>
        <td>Good</td>
        <td>200 Bags</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
        <td></td>
        <td>Rice</td>
        <td>Good</td>
        <td>100 Bags</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
        <td></td>
        <td>Rice</td>
        <td>Good</td>
        <td>100 Bags</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
        <td></td>
        <td>Sugar</td>
        <td>Prime</td>
        <td>200 Bags</td>
    </tr>            
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
        <td></td>
        <td>Maze</td>
        <td>Fine</td>
        <td>10 Packs</td>
    </tr>            
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
        <td></td>
        <td>Sugar</td>
        <td>Prime</td>
        <td>200 Bags</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
        <td></td>
        <td>Sugar</td>
        <td>Prime</td>
        <td>200 Bags</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
        <td>Sugar</td>
        <td>Prime</td>
        <td>200 Bags</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
        <td></td>
        <td>Sugar</td>
        <td>Prime</td>
        <td>200 Bags</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
        <td></td>
        <td>Sugar</td>
        <td>Prime</td>
        <td>200 Bags</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
        <td></td>
        <td>Sugar</td>
        <td>Prime</td>
        <td>200 Bags</td>
    </tr>        
    </tbody>    
</table>
</div>

<script>
function queryParams() {
    return {
        type: 'owner',
        sort: 'updated',
        direction: 'desc',
        per_page: 100,
        page: 1
    };
}
function rowColors(row, index) {
    var classes = ['active', 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger'];
    
    if (index % 2 === 0 && index / 2 < classes.length) {
        return {
            classes: classes[index / 2]
        };
    }
    return {};
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**My actual code is here**

```
<html>
<body>
<label for="fname">insert number for select multiple check box</label>
    <input type="number" id="selectcheckbox" name="selectcheckbox">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tbl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>SELECT check box is here</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
            var table = $('#tbl').DataTable({
            "columnDefs": 
            [
            {
                orderable: false,
                className: 'select-checkbox',
                targets:   0
            }
            ],
          destroy:true,
          "fnRowCallback" : 
          function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex)
          {
              $("td:first", nRow).html(iDisplayIndex +1);
              return nRow;
          },      
          'select': 
          {
              style: 'multi',
              selector:'td:nth-child(1)'
          },
              'order': [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
          });
          
          $.ajax({
          type:"POST", 
          url:"fetch_data.php",  
          data:'value='+value,
            success: function(data)
            {
              if(data['error'] == '0')
              {
                console.log(data);
                  
                  //set Finish Data
                  table.clear().draw();
                  for(i = 0; i < data['chemical_date'].length; i++) 
                  {
                    table.row.add([
                    data['chemical_date'][i]['value'],
                    data['chemical_date'][i]['value'],
                    data['chemical_date'][i]['value'],
                    data['chemical_date'][i]['value'],
                    data['chemical_date'][i]['value'],
                    data['chemical_date'][i]['value'],
                    data['chemical_date'][i]['value'],
                
                    "<input type='text' value='' class='form-control' id='selectedqty"+i+"' onkeyup='sqty(this.id);' name='selectedqty"+i+"'/>",
                    "<input type='text' value='' class='form-control ' id='note"+i+"'  name='note"+i+"' />",
                    "<input type='text' value='' class='form-control ' id='location"+i+"'  name='location"+i+"' />",
                    '',
                    '',
                    ''
                    ]).draw(false);
                  }
              }
            }
          })
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**fetch_data.php**

```
<?php
$response = array();
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
    extract($_POST);
    //Top data
        $data = array();
        $obj = array(); 
        $sql = "some query here...";

            $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
            $chemical = array();
        
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
                //Finish Data
                $row1 = array();
                $row1['value'] = $row['value'];
                $row1['value'] = $row['value'];
                $row1['value'] = $row['value'];
                $row1['value'] = $row['value'];
                $row1['value'] = $row['value'];
                $row1['value'] = $row['value'];
                $row1['value'] = $row['value'];
                array_push($chemical, $row1);
                //Stock Data
            }
            $response['chemical_date'] = $chemical;
            //Process Data
            $response['error'] = "0";
}
else
    $response['error'] = "1";
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for-loop then inside this use `:eq()` to checked checkboxes according to index values .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function queryParams() {
  return {
    type: 'owner',
    sort: 'updated',
    direction: 'desc',
    per_page: 100,
    page: 1
  };
}

function rowColors(row, index) {
  var classes = ['active', 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger'];

  if (index % 2 === 0 && index / 2 < classes.length) {
    return {
      classes: classes[index / 2]
    };
  }
  return {};
}

$("#selectcheckbox").on("change", function() {
  $("[name=btSelectItem]").prop("checked", false) //unchecked..
  //loop
  for (let i = 0; i < $(this).val(); i++) {
    //if that elemnt exist
    if ($("[name=btSelectItem]:eq(" + i + ")").length > 0) {
      $("[name=btSelectItem]:eq(" + i + ")").prop("checked", true) //checked it
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<label for="fname">insert number for select multiple check box</label>
<input type="number" id="selectcheckbox" name="selectcheckbox">
<table data-toggle="table" data-classes="table table-hover table-condensed" data-row-style="rowColors" data-striped="true" data-sort-name="Quality" data-sort-order="desc" data-pagination="true" data-click-to-select="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
      <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="Product_Name" data-sortable="true">Product Name</th>
      <th class="col-xs-1" data-field="Quality" data-sortable="true">Quality</th>
      <th class="col-xs-6" data-field="Quantity">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
      <td></td>
      <td>Wheat</td>
      <td>Good</td>
      <td>200 Bags</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
      <td></td>
      <td>Rice</td>
      <td>Good</td>
      <td>100 Bags</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
      <td></td>
      <td>Rice</td>
      <td>Good</td>
      <td>100 Bags</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
      <td></td>
      <td>Sugar</td>
      <td>Prime</td>
      <td>200 Bags</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
      <td></td>
      <td>Maze</td>
      <td>Fine</td>
      <td>10 Packs</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
      <td></td>
      <td>Sugar</td>
      <td>Prime</td>
      <td>200 Bags</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
      <td></td>
      <td>Sugar</td>
      <td>Prime</td>
      <td>200 Bags</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
      <td>Sugar</td>
      <td>Prime</td>
      <td>200 Bags</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
      <td></td>
      <td>Sugar</td>
      <td>Prime</td>
      <td>200 Bags</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
      <td></td>
      <td>Sugar</td>
      <td>Prime</td>
      <td>200 Bags</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
      <td></td>
      <td>Sugar</td>
      <td>Prime</td>
      <td>200 Bags</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

***Update 1*** :

As you are using `select-checkbox` so plugin doesn't create checkbox itself they are handle by *css* code(adding checked) . So , after looking at html generated when we *check* any checkbox it adds `selected` class to `tr` so  we can simply use `addClass("selected")` to make the row selected and checked.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
      orderable: false,
      className: 'select-checkbox',
      targets: 0
    }],
    select: {
      style: 'multi',
      selector: 'td:nth-child(1)'
    },
    order: [
      [1, 'asc']
    ]
  });


  $("#selectcheckbox").on("change", function() {
    //remove selected class
    $("#example tr").removeClass("selected")
    for (let i = 0; i < $(this).val(); i++) {
      //check if td there ...
      if ($("#example td.select-checkbox:eq(" + i + ")").length > 0) {
        //add selected class..
        $("#example td.select-checkbox:eq(" + i + ")").closest("tr").addClass("selected") //try with `.click()` as well..
      }

    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.3/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="selectcheckbox" name="selectcheckbox">
<table id="example" class="stripe row-border order-column nowrap" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Garrett</td>
      <td>Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Ashton</td>
      <td>Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cedric</td>
      <td>Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Airi</td>
      <td>Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But, I am not sure if this is right solution :)

Comment: Im using Jquery datatable and fetch data using ajax there in no input in checkbox ```<td class="bs-checkbox "><input data-index="0" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>```

Comment: I got only this ```<td class=" select-checkbox">1</td>```

Comment: What was that previous code then ? You are using datatable ? But in question you have added boostrap table ?

Comment: can u please check my above new code... yeah my previous code were I trying to implement with my old code..

Comment: Its working, I mean its get selected but as you said you did this by calling class, after get selected I also wanted to store this data into the data base that time it will work? I mean it will stored that as selected rows data in database?..

Comment: I am not sure . Try that and see if that works or not . Alternative way instead of  `select-checkbox`  use actual checkbox(create them while you initialize your datatables) . Also , i didn't find anything on google related to this .

Comment: You can upvote and accept this answer if this solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should select the checkbox in the first TD of every row based on the number

```
$('#selectcheckbox').on('input', function() {
  let num = $(this).val();
  $('.table td:first-child input[type="checkbox"]').each(function (index) {
    if (index <= num-1) $(this).prop("checked", true);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example in vanilla JS.

```js
// Grab the input, and the input boxes
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('table input[type="checkbox"]');

// Add an event listener to the input to watch for changes
input.addEventListener('change', handleClick, false);

function handleClick() {

  // Grab the number from the input box
  // (it's a string so you have to coerce it to a number)
  const number = Number(input.value);

  // If the number is less than or equal to the
  // number of input boxes...
  if (number <= inputs.length) {

    // ...loop through the boxes
    // and check them if they match the number
    // and uncheck them if they don't
    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      if (i < number) {
        inputs[i].checked = 'checked';
      } else {
        inputs[i].checked = '';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" />
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" /></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```